# Is there a term to describe starting a sentence with its intention?

Tags: phrases, expressions

This is common in the depiction of monotone robots in sci-fi. For example,

- "Statement: You are only human, after all."
- "Reassure: This will only hurt a little."
- "Question: Why are you in charge again?"

How would one describe this pattern?

Comment: Wouldn't you call it "robotic"?

Comment: In-line commentary. 'Running commentary' is a fixed phrase / compound, of course.